# How can I run mics with xlr into an old (ancient) mixer with 1/4 TS inputs?

Tags: microphone, recording, mixer, xlr

Output from the mixer will go to a recording program on a tablet (we've got that part figured out). Reason for doing this is the band I'm in wants to create some practice tracks for the songs we are doing. The rhythm guitarist/lead vocalist will lay down his tracks and the rest of the band can play/practice their parts over top. We have a large 24 channel mixer with xlr inputs, etc for gigs but its not practical to set it up in the space where this is going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to get a smaller mixer with XLR support, or get a bunch of DI boxes with XLR in and unbalanced 1/4" outputs.

Both are good solutions, but the DI one is possibly more useful. I have a bunch of Behringer DI boxes with balanced and unbalanced inputs and outputs which always come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

If the 1/4" TS inputs are microphone and not line inputs, it's likely they are designed for unbalanced Hi-Z mics (especially on older gear), in which case you will need a step up transformer to bring the impedance of a regular Lo-Z mic like an SM-57 to Hi-Z. There are many [commercially available products](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006NMUHW) that do this.

A DI would be a step down transformer and may not be appropriate in this case. DI's are for bringing Hi-Z instruments down to Lo-Z mic level. You are kind of trying to do the opposite.